# Asp.Net Core 2 Web API shows HTTP 404 error on Visual Studio 2017, Windows 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have just pulled one Asp.Net Core 2 Web API project from GitHub, and when I try to run the application via IISExpress it always throws HTTP 404 error. The build is always successful. I am running it from Visual Studio 2017 on my Windows machine.

[image]

Things I have tried:

- Tried different browsers
- Checked my proxy settings
- Used `.UseIISIntegration()` in my Program.cs file

  ```
  public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
      WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .UseStartup<Startup>()
      .UseIISIntegration()
      .Build();
  ```
- Deleted the `.vs` folder from the app directory and tried again

Nothing seems to be working. Has anyone else faced this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found that this was the issue with Asp.Net code 2. When I run the application, it is actually loading the URL as *localhost:49515* as a default launching URL and it was returning HTTP 404. This [post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/77206/running-net-core-webapi-project-leads-to-404.html) helped me find the actual issue. When I try with any default API link *localhost:49515/api/values*, it is working fine.

You can always set the custom launch URL by following these steps.

- Right-click on the project, and click on properties
- Got to Debug
- Check the Launch browser checkbox and set the URL there (http://localhost:49515/api/values)

[image]

Now run your application, it will open the new URL always.